# Install Jenkin's Plugin without Restart

Tags: plugins, jenkins, installation

How to install my own jenkins plugin without jenkins restart. I have seen in update center it install plugins without restart but I am not able to install my own plugins without restart. Please let me know how to do it. I am using Jenkins 1.509.2

Answer (score 10):

During installation of a plugin you can select "Install without restart" button.

[image]

However, because of the architectual choice made in Jenkins, this same scheme wouldn't allow us to upgrade existing plugins. Jenkins added the plugin support in 1.44, since that time Jenkins required a restart for new plugins to take effect. This is because we load plugins at start-up, doing all kinds of computation to build up the immutable data structure around all the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Installing custom plugin for the first time is working Good without restart. But when I would like to perform an update to the plugin then it is specifying that I should restart the Jenkins server for sure.

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking about how to install a plugin you personally developed without restarting, not a plugin from the plugins repo, you can do so by going to:
Jenkins>Plugin Manager, click the Advanced tab.

There you'll see "Upload Plugin". Upload the hpi file for the plugin. You don't need to restart the Jenkins. All running jobs will not be disrupted. Your plugin should show up after. This method hasn't been tested for all plugins, but it has worked for some simple ones.